# How we can set THERMAL_DEFAULT_GOV_POWER_ALLOCATOR as a default thermal governor on Linux?

Tags: embedded-linux

I'm working to control the fans on an embedded system, currently I'm using **step wise thermal governo**r which is the default one on Linux. So I would like to test **power allocator thermal governor** which is a closed loop control, but I don't know how to setup it !